# node webkit- catch iframe mouse events from parent window

Tags: javascript, node.js, iframe, node-webkit

I'm trying to create a draggable iframe in my app. When the iframe is focused, all mouse events are triggered within the inner window object.

- I can't listen to those events within the iframe and trigger them myself, because it can be blocked by the iframe content js
- I can't create an unvisible layer above the iframe that will catch all the events and move them forward to the iframe, because bultin events  can't be triggered by script (like css `hover`)
- can I catch those events in Node layer, without using webkit DOM?

Comment: Node is javascript, but it is not at the client side.  It doesn't know about the DOM or mouse events, it just delivers content to the client. So, I'm going to go out on a limb here and say it's not possible.

Comment: Can't node communicate with native mouse events, like any native GUI app?

Comment: It doesn't look like it.  It does make it easy to include node modules in the html code, but that's different than node knowing about mouse events.

Answer (score 1):

One idea I have is to place a transparent element (like a **div**) in front of your **iframe** and then intercept the click and mouse move events there to make the iframe drag around.

I've done so here in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/y8YrMB?p=preview).

The code, as you see below, is just enough to get across this idea and what steps are required to get the iframe to move around. It has some flaws (move your mouse quickly) but you could do some things to resolve those issues.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <style>
      iframe, div {
        position: absolute;
        left: 20px;
        top: 20px;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <iframe id="iframe" src="if.html"></iframe>
    <div id="div" onmousedown="startDrag(event)" onmouseup="stopDrag()" onmousemove="moveDrag(event)"></div>
  </body>


  <script>
    var objDiv = document.getElementById("div");
    var objDivCoordinates = {left: 20, top: 20};
    var objIframe = document.getElementById("iframe");
    var mouseX = null;
    var mouseY = null;
    var dragging = false;

    function startDrag(e) {
      mouseX = e.clientX;
      mouseY = e.clientY;
      dragging = true;
      objIframe.contentWindow.document.writeln("Starting Drag...<br>");
    }
    function moveDrag(e) {
      if(!dragging) return;

      var changeX = mouseX - e.clientX;
      var changeY = mouseY - e.clientY;

      objDivCoordinates.left -= changeX;
      objDivCoordinates.top -= changeY;
      objDiv.style.left = objDivCoordinates.left+"px";
      objDiv.style.top = objDivCoordinates.top+"px";
      objIframe.style.left = objDiv.style.left;
      objIframe.style.top = objDiv.style.top;

      mouseX = e.clientX;
      mouseY = e.clientY;
    }
    function stopDrag(e) {
      dragging = false;
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried it. The prublem is that bultin events, like hover, can't be triggered by script. Maybe with node webkit you can?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question.  I think I understand it better now.  You want to be able to drag the iframe when it **is not** in focus, but also have events delivered into the iframe when it **is** in focus. Is that correct?

Comment: No. also when the iframe is in focus, I want being able to catch the mouse events in his parent

Comment: Well, you can do something like `objIframe.contentWindow.document.writeln("Starting Drag...<br>");` to execute some code inside of the iframe ([found here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/251420/invoking-javascript-code-in-an-iframe-from-the-parent-page)). Any way to make it work like that?

Comment: If I'm listening to a mouse event by `Iframe.contentWindow.document`, another script can cancel it easily

Answer (score 1):

You could try creating a plain `EventEmitter` and storing it on node's `global` object.  Since `global` is accessible in all node-webkit contexts, the iframe could use it to `emit` things that it wants the parent window to know about, and the parent can likewise use it to `emit` events that the `iframe` may want to know about.

Is this a solution that might work for you?

Comment: The question is, how can I catch all mouse events from the iFrame, without allowing cancel the catching from there. If I'm listening to a click event by `Iframe.contentWindow.document`, another script can cancel it easily

Answer (score 1):

From what I see you are the most concerned about a situation when some other script cancels execution of your listener (by calling `stopPropagation`), but you can prevent such situation altogether.

[**`addEventListener(type, listener [, useCapture])`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) allows to pass a `useCapture` argument, which defaults to `false`. If you set it to `true` then you are safe:

> After initiating capture, all events of the specified type will be
>   dispatched to the registered listener before being dispatched to any
>   EventTarget beneath it in the DOM tree.